# how can I use autoplay for iframe & target for video

Tags: html

I study html5.
i want to make main video, and another video click - change main video
if i can more, how can use autoplay for iframe?
i use allow="autoplay", but it dnt work
thank you for ur support

```
// <iframe width="200" height="200" src="ex01.mp4" name="exname01" >
</iframe>
<br>
<a href="ex02.mp4" target="exname01">
<video src="02.mp4"width="100" height="100"></a> //
```

Comment: Not enough info on your full setup bruh

Comment: Please elaborate. but you can just check if your site-settings have blocked autoplay or your plugins in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should add more context but here is something that could possibly work:

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="ex01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: and how can i another videos for target??

Comment: i am unsure based on the content you provided. Please provide more details and all of your pages code. i may be able to help if you do.